# No puedo guardar el excel que estoy Leyendo y escribiendo

Tags: c#, windows-forms, excel, .net, librería

```
private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Ubicacion del Excel
            string fileLocation =
            @"C:\Users\Randi\Desktop\Bussiness\Calc\DataBase\Usuarios.xlsx";

            //Verificando si existe el archivo
            if (File.Exists(fileLocation)) 
            {

                SLDocument excel = new SLDocument(fileLocation);
                string c = "", s = "";
                int i = 1;

                //Estoy recorriendo algunas celdas y obteniendo su valor
                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(excel.GetCellValueAsString(1, i)))
                {
                    c += excel.GetCellValueAsString(1, i) + "\n";
                    s += excel.GetCellValueAsString(2, i) + "\n";
                    i++;
                }
                //Pasandole valor a una celda
                excel.SetCellValue(2, 2, "GoodBye WOrld!");
                //Leyendo la misma celda para verificar la escritura anterior
                s = excel.GetCellValueAsString(2, 2);
                //Mostrando informacion de las celdas en cuadro de textos
                textBox1.Text = c;
                textBox2.Text = s;

                //Se supone que esta funcion guarda los cambios
                excel.Save();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Base De Datos No encontrada", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Este Código me permite leer y escribir en un archivo de Excel existente gracias a la librería de  SpreadSheetLight, la cual tiene muchas funcionalidades para manejar un excel mediante código, una de ellas es `Save()` o `SaveAs()` que te permiten guardar el excel que estas administrando ya sea en su misma ubicación o en otra distinta, probando las funciones me sale el error que no pueden haber multiples instancias del excel pero al crear un objeto de la clase `SLDocument` solo estoy creando uno y guardandolo con el mismo objeto que tiene la dirección del excel. [image: Para más detalles]

Gracias por dedicarme unos minutos de su tiempo :)

Comment: Tienes abierto el archivo en Office Excel?  así funciona excel no puedes abrir el mismo archivo dos veces, lo mismo va ha pasar si lo quieres modificar desde c# y lo tienes abierto en office

Comment: Tambien si ya abriste el archivo antes en otra parte del Código y no lo cerraste... es como si lo tuvieras abierto dos veces, lo que debes hacer es utilizar using(){} asi como se hace com los streamreaders, con eso te aseguras de cerrarlo cada vez que lo abres.

Comment: El archivo siempre lo mantengo cerrado, incluso reviso en el administrador de tareas por si esta en segundo plano, probaré lo del using(){}

Comment: ¿te sirvió la respuesta? Por favor, si es así, finaliza la pregunta. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en el código, no llegas a cerrar la instancia nunca. Save solo guarda los cambios en el fichero excel pero no vacías la variable objeto, al menos en excel vba es así, no sé si en c# es diferente, entiendo que no.
Prueba a poner debajo del Save:

```
excel = Nothing
```

Por otro lado, si has implementado el uso de Using, para controlar errores, te vendrá bien dejarlo para no dejar instancias abandonadas, lo que provoca siempre comportamientos no deseados.

Por cierto, comentas que miras el administrador de tareas para ver si tienes instancias...En verdad es mejor mirar los procesos (en windows, entiendo que estás).  Dichos Procesos se ven con Control+AlT+SUP y después en la pestaña Detalles están listados. En verdad es lo mismo, pero en la pantalla principal de Procesos se ven los procesos por aplicación y a veces es algo confuso. En cambio si lo miras en pestaña Detalle..se ve un Excel.exe en ejecución.

Por otro lado, y perdona por se tan pesado (me ha pasado) también sería bueno ver si la biblioteca que usas desde c# permite usar:

```
excel.close()
```

Viene mejor tener también el control de cuando está abierto el fichero y saber que lo has cerrado. Siendo el orden:

```
excel.save()
excel.close()
excel = Nothing
```